# How to know which features causes anomalies while training isolation forest model

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection, isolation-forest

I'm training an unsupersived isolation forest model with a dataframe that contains 10 features , the model performs well and detect anomalies.
My question is if an anomaly is catched i want to know which feature(s) has caused that anomaly.
Is there any way to do it ?
If not , is there an other model that allows me to do it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory an/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Comment: Essentially answered in the Cross Validated thread [How to get top features that contribute to anomalies in Isolation forest](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404017/how-to-get-top-features-that-contribute-to-anomalies-in-isolation-forest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHAP values and the [shap library](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) can be used for this. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404017/how-to-get-top-features-that-contribute-to-anomalies-in-isolation-forest/451518#451518) for an example.

After getting the shap values out of the explainer for your datapoints, you can use the [waterfall plots](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/api_examples/plots/waterfall.html) to see how different features contributed to the decision.

```py
shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[0])
```

It will give a plot similar to this:

[image]