# "Most outlier" feature

Tags: scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection, feature-engineering, isolation-forest

I am using the [Sklearn implementation of Isolation Forest (IF)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html) to detect outliers on a set of data of 20-30 features.

It is working very well, but I would like insight into which feature has the highest impact when an outlier is detected. Please note that my goal is not to get the feature importance (ie. which feature the IF model relies on most to detect outliers) but rather, in the case of this one specific outlier that was flagged as a -1, which feature was the furthest form the median/mean/cluster, etc...

Does this make sense?

Comment: Take a look to this [link](https://www.data4v.com/machine-learning-interpretability-for-isolation-forest-using-shap/). Maybe it could help you.

Comment: See this answer, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451518/201327

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674401/1967571